# Show that if $f$ is onto then $f(x)=g(x)$ for some $x\in X$.

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $X$ be a connected space and let $f; g : X \to [0, 1]$ be continuous functions. Prove that if $f$ is onto, then $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x \in X$.

So I'm saying the following:

Let $E$ be a dense subset of $X$. For any a in $X$ let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $E$ converging to $a$. Then:
$$f(a)=\lim f(x_n)=\lim g(x_n)=g(a)$$
hence 
$f(x)=g(x)$ for some $x \in X$

Can I be sure that such a dense $E$ exists?

Comment: Is the space at least Hausdorff? If not how are you defining convergence to a point? Are you at all interested in the answer with the generalized notion of "dense" rather than the sequential one?

Comment: I'm not sure what this question is asking. Take $X$ to be connected (and nonempty), choose the subset to be the whole space, and choose the sequence to be the constant sequence $x_n = x$ for some $x\in X$. Then $x\in X$ is a limit of $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: Regardless of what may or may not be true for $X$ (which is irrelevant in the scheme of your work), your attempt of proof is circular. It seems to me that you want to say that $f(a)=g(a)$ by picking a sequence $x_n$ of points such that $x_n\to a$ and $g(x_n)=f(x_n)$ for all $n$. But then, what would you need $a$ for?

Comment: Pretty much every response has just told you that your approach is wrong and not suggested anything better. The problem is that you asked a specific question that doesn't really make sense as part of a larger question that *does* make sense. I've gone ahead and edited the post and nominated it for a reopen. The correct approach is as such: if $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for all $x$, then let $A=\{x:f(x)>g(x)\}$, and $B=\{x:f(x)<g(x)\}$. Both are nonempty because $f$ is onto, and they union to all of $X$. Show that both are open (using continuity) to contradict the connectedness of $X$.

Comment: I think it is important to notice that this reflects a non-trivial property of $[0,1]$ (so it is kind of a question in algebraic topology although as shown in the comment by @AlexMathers it admits a simple solution in terms of general topology). For example this is not true if you replace $[0,1]$ by the unit circle $S^1$ (take $f$ to be the identity and $g$ a non-trivial rotation).

Answer (score 2):

The question is alright, but what you are "saying" doesn't make any sense.

It's very simple: By assumption there are $a$ and $b\in X$ with $f(a)=0$, $f(b)=1$. If $g(a)=0$ or $g(b)=1$ we are done. Otherwise the continuous function $h(x):=f(x)-g(x)$ satisfies $h(a)<0$, $h(b)>0$. If $h$ would have no zero on $X$ the union of the two nonempty, open, and disjoint sets
$$\Omega_1:=\{x\in X\>|\>h(x)<0\}\ ,\qquad \Omega_2:=\{x\in X\>|\>h(x)>0\}\ $$
would be $X$, contrary to the assumption on $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Every topological space is a dense subset of itself (connectedness is unnecessary). And you can use a constant sequence which necessarily converges. Do be careful about convergence in general topological spaces, though, uniqueness of the limit is not guaranteed unless it's Hausdorff.